# Knockout JS Count only numbers in maxLength attribute

Tags: html, knockout.js

Is there a way to manipulate maxLength attribute to count only numbers?
I have seen this code `MyObservable.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').length` that can only count numbers but I don't know where to put it. Or any better Idea. Thanks

Comment: `Maxlength` looks at the number of characters, not just numbers. What's your use case here? You might need a different approach.

Comment: yes I need another way to compute maxlength with counting only numbers because I have something like tax rate input and allows Decimal and `max value of 100`, but I don't want to include the dot (.) in counting length and I don't want to have thousands value, so `maxLength="3" or maxlength="5"` is not what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a custom binding if you want to limit to a certain amount instead of the length of a string. There's 2 options, with one you remain with an `input="text"` and the second being an `input="number"`

The difference that with the first you'll need to include a regex somewhat like your example into the following piece of code, where with the second option the browser has already taken care of that, I'll leave it up to you where you want to go with this.

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.maxValue = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var valueObservable = valueAccessor();

        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
            var value = Number(element.value);
          if (value >= 0) {
            if (value > allBindings().maxAmount) {
                value = allBindings().maxAmount;
            }
            element.value = value;
            valueObservable(value);
          }
        });
    },
};

var ViewModel = function ()
{
    var self = this;
  self.value = ko.observable();
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="number" data-bind="maxValue: $root.value, maxAmount: 100" />
```